# How to deal with multiple authors returned from books-table query

Tags: php, mysql, database

Previously I stored the author names into my books-table which isn't the best practice. So I outsourced the authors to a separate table and joined the data via pivot table. My query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT  b.id, b.title, CONCAT(a.fname,' ' , a.lname) AS author_name, a.id as author_id
FROM books b
LEFT JOIN author_book ab ON b.id = ab.book_id
LEFT JOIN authors a ON ab.author_id = a.id
WHERE b.id = '406'
```

So far everything works fine but my query returns not only one row of data but two of them - one for each author.

```sql
id  | title                          |  author_name      | author_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------
406 | The world of the wheel of time | Robert Jordan     | 2
406 | The world of the wheel of time | Teresa Patterson  | 3
```

But I really want to output only one book with multiple authors - not multiple books with one author. In this example it's not hard to do this but what happens when I search for books with short storys? Up to dozen authors are involved. Then the returned result could look a like in this example:

```sql
id  | title                          |  author_name      | author_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------
103 | Here Be Monsters               | M.T. Murphy       | 12
103 | Here Be Monsters               | S.M. Reine        | 6
103 | Here Be Monsters               | India Drummond    | 182
103 | Here Be Monsters               | Anabel Portillo   | 643
103 | Here Be Monsters               | Jeremy C. Shipp   | 35
103 | Here Be Monsters               | Samantha Anderson | 58
103 | Here Be Monsters               | Sara Reinke       | 26
521 | Science Fiction Megapack       | Fritz Leiber      | 19
521 | Science Fiction Megapack       | C.M. Kornbluth    | 27
521 | Science Fiction Megapack       | Philip K. Dick    | 24
521 | Science Fiction Megapack       | E.C. Tubb         | 46
521 | Science Fiction Megapack       | John Glasby       | 67
```

I can try to use GROUP BY id or title but then the authors would get lost but one. (some php array operations may be a solution?). How would you output this data so each book will stay a single entity with all of it's authors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider using `GROUP_CONCAT()`  like this:

```
SELECT
  b.id,
  b.title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.fname,' ' , a.lname)) AS author_names,
  GROUP_CONCAT(a.id) as author_ids
FROM books b
LEFT JOIN author_book ab
  ON b.id = ab.book_id
LEFT JOIN authors a
  ON ab.author_id = a.id
WHERE b.id = '406'
GROUP BY b.id
```

That would give you output like:

```
406 | The world of the wheel of time | Robert Jordan,Teresa Patterson     | 2,3
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is the perfect solution! Thank you so much Mike, you make my day!